# how to change the ejs template in node.js to avoid this situation

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using the ejs template in the node.js, and I have troubles with routes, so for example

I have two html files, home.html and list.html, which both load a list.ejs file in order to show the same content - a list of users.

**home.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid content">   
    <% include users/list %>        
</div>
```

**list.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid content">   
    <% include course/list %>       
</div>
```

**list.ejs**

```
    <article>
        <h2><a href="user/<%= user._id %>" ></a><%= user.title %></h2>
        <p>
            <a href="user/<%= user._id %>" >@waynespiegel</a><%= user.description %>
        </p>
    </article>
```

however, the problem arises that home.html and list.html are in different url, 
the url of home.html is **'/'** while the url of home.html is **'user/recent'**.

so if I click the " ><%= user.title %> in the home.html page, it correctly jump to the right page, **/user/'userid'**. but when it comes to the list.html, the link becomes **/user/user/'userid'**, which is wrong

so my question is how can I change the ejs to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a slash in the beginning of the url you make it relative to the base url. Normally that's your domain.

```
<article>
    <h2><a href="/user/<%= user._id %>" ></a><%= user.title %></h2>
    <p>
        <a href="/user/<%= user._id %>" >@waynespiegel</a><%= user.description %>
    </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your new list.ejs:

```
<article>
    <h2><a href="/user/<%= user._id %>" ></a><%= user.title %></h2>
    <p>
        <a href="/user/<%= user._id %>" >@waynespiegel</a><%= user.description %>
    </p>
</article>
```

Without the leading / in your links, you were calling up to a relative path, now you are dealing with an absolute path (ie: starting from your server root).